Problem in query that returns information from Oracle customers by site
My query should have only the records that were modified in sysdate
SELECT 
/*********hz_parties******************/
       hp.party_id,
       hp.party_name,
       hp.jgzz_fiscal_code,
       To_char(hp.creation_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
/*********hz_party_sites******************/
       hps.party_site_id,
       hps.party_site_number,
/*********hz_organization_profiles******************/      
       hop.attribute2,
       hop.attribute1,
       hop.attribute3,
/*********hz_locations******************/
       hzl.attribute6,
       hzl.postal_code,
       hzl.address1,
       hzl.addr_element_attribute3,
       hzl.state,
       hzl.addr_element_attribute2,
       hzl.city,
       hzl.attribute1,
       CASE
         WHEN hzl.attribute7 IS NULL THEN NULL
         ELSE (SELECT vst1.description
               FROM   fnd_vs_values_b VSV1,
                      fnd_vs_values_tl VST1
               WHERE  vsv1.value = hzl.attribute7
                      AND vsv1.attribute_category = 'Periodo de facturación'
                      AND vsv1.value_id = vst1.value_id
                      AND vsv1.enterprise_id = vst1.enterprise_id
                      AND vsv1.sandbox_id = vst1.sandbox_id
                      AND vst1.language = 'E')
       END                                     "PeriodoFacturacionId",
       hzl.attribute4                          "LimiteCredito",
       hzl.attribute3                          "ClienteId",
       /*********vendor******************/
       (SELECT vst1.description
        FROM   fnd_vs_values_b VSV1,
               fnd_vs_values_tl VST1
        WHERE  vsv1.value = hzl.attribute2
               AND vsv1.attribute_category = 'Vendedor'
               AND vsv1.value_id = vst1.value_id
               AND vsv1.enterprise_id = vst1.enterprise_id
               AND vsv1.sandbox_id = vst1.sandbox_id
               AND vst1.language = 'E')        "Vendedor",
        /*********others******************/
FROM   hz_parties hp,
       hz_party_sites hps,
       hz_organization_profiles hop,
       hz_locations hzl
WHERE 
/*********hz_parties---hz_party_sites******************/
       hp.party_type = 'ORGANIZATION'
   AND hp.party_id = hps.party_id
/*********hz_parties---hz_organization_profiles******************/
   AND hp.party_id = hop.party_id
/*********hz_party_sites---hz_locations******************/
AND hps.location_id = hzl.location_id
AND ((Trunc(HP.CREATION_DATE) = Trunc(SYSDATE)) OR
     (Trunc(hop.LAST_UPDATE_DATE) = Trunc(SYSDATE)) OR
     Trunc(hzl.LAST_UPDATE_DATE) = Trunc(SYSDATE))

I'm working on a query to get information about customers by site.
For example, if a customer has 10 sites and I modify only one, it should skip the other 9 and only return the one I modified, however it gives me the information for the 10 sites in total
Of the 4 tables I'm using:

hz_parties
hz_party_sites
hz_organization_profiles
hz_locations

The change can only occur in the tables:

hz_organization_profiles
hz_locations


Please [edit] the question and provide a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements that includes relational constraints for a minimal example of the problem (your current query uses 5 tables and returns ~20 columns, most of which are irrelevant to the problem - simplify the problem to 2 or 3 tables and 3-5 columns to make it easier to understand); an English (not code) explanation of the logic that you are trying to implement; and the expected output for your sample data.

Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit JOIN syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Your WHERE conditions doesn't restrict on the rows being of the same party_id.
If you where using modern JOIN syntax you should have seen it earlier.

There are 4 tables and the OP has given 3 join conditions, which are presumably on the primary keys (and there may not be a party_id column in the hz_locations table), which would be sufficient to INNER JOIN all the tables so the use of ANSI joins syntax vs legacy comma-join syntax is not obvious that it is the source of the OP's issue.

Without the table descriptions, sample data and expected result it is hard to tell what you need to do.
There is an issue with :

... if a customer has 10 sites and I modify only one, it should skip the other 9 and only return the one I modified

.. but you didn't modify sites ...

The change can only occur in the tables:
hz_organization_profiles and hz_locations

... the result depends on your data and on JOIN condition possibilities and/or Where clause filtering possibilities. Without the sample data I could only offer a simplified example of what could be the issue...
S a m p l e    D a t a :
hz_parties;



PARTY_ID
PARTY_NAME
CREATION_DATE




1
party 1
11-OCT-24


2
party 2
13-OCT-24


3
party 3
17-OCT-24



hz_party_sites;



PARTY_SITE_ID
PARTY_SITE_NUMBER
PARTY_ID
LOCATION_ID
LAST_UPDATE_DATE




101
10
1
15
11-OCT-24


102
20
2
25
13-OCT-24


103
30
3
35
14-OCT-24


104
40
3
25
15-OCT-24


105
50
3
15
17-OCT-24



hz_locations;



LOCATION_ID
CITY
LAST_UPDATE_DATE




15
Galway
11-OCT-24


25
Barcelona
13-OCT-24


35
Amsterdam
17-OCT-24



hz_organization_profiles;



ID
PARTY_ID
ATTRIBUTE1
ATTRIBUTE2
ATTRIBUTE3
LAST_UPDATE_DATE




11
1
A1
A2
A3
11-OCT-24


12
2
B1
B2
B3
13-OCT-24


13
3
C1
C2
C3
18-OCT-24



SYSDATE() is 18-OCT-24
--      S Q L : 
SELECT       hp.party_id, hp.party_name, To_char(hp.creation_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as creation_date,
             hps.party_site_id, hps.party_site_number, 
             hop.attribute2, hop.attribute1, hop.attribute3,
             hzl.city 
FROM         hz_parties hp 
LEFT JOIN    hz_party_sites hps ON( hps.party_id = hp.party_id)
LEFT JOIN    hz_organization_profiles hop ON( hop.party_id = hp.party_id)
LEFT JOIN    hz_locations hzl ON( hzl.location_id = hps.location_id )
WHERE      ( Trunc(HP.CREATION_DATE) = Trunc(SYSDATE) OR
             Trunc(hop.LAST_UPDATE_DATE) = Trunc(SYSDATE) OR
             Trunc(hzl.LAST_UPDATE_DATE) = Trunc(SYSDATE)
           );

R e s u l t :



PARTY_ID
PARTY_NAME
CREATION_DATE
PARTY_SITE_ID
PARTY_SITE_NUMBER
ATTRIBUTE2
ATTRIBUTE1
ATTRIBUTE3
CITY




3
party 3
17/10/2024
105
50
C2
C1
C3
Galway


3
party 3
17/10/2024
104
40
C2
C1
C3
Barcelona


3
party 3
17/10/2024
103
30
C2
C1
C3
Amsterdam



Having multiple sites (for one party_id) joined to different locations (and/or profiles) you need to find,  within your actual context,the way to select just the row you need out of above 3 rows.
That could be done using either additional join condition(s) or additional Where condition(s) or both. Could that be a condition on party_site_id or party_site_number? Do you have it in any other table?
OR
You could provide table descriptions, sample data and expected result ...
fiddle
